# How can I read JSON Information?

Tags: javascript, json

So I have some code and I want it so my JavaScript code will read the JSON information and then give them access to a staff panel. Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "User1": {
        "User": "Elliott",
        "StaffPanelAdvanced": "true"
    },
    "User2": {
        "User": "Max",
        "StaffPanelAdvanced": "true"
    },
    "Password:": "2201-hrstaffpanel"
}
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```js
let pr = prompt("What is your staff name? (Case Sensitive)")
                    if (pr === data.User1.User) {
                        alert("Logged in successfully, " + pr + ".")
}
```

(By the way, I am using 'fetch' to fetch the JSON info since 'require' would not work.)
Why will this not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `fetch` make sure to parse the JSON response to object.

```
      fetch('url')
        .then((response) => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.statusText)
          }
          return response.json() // Parse JSON response
        })
        .then((data) => {
           // You can access data as object now.
           console.log(data)
        })
```

Comment: It worked but I cannot access the password, it returns undefined when I to 'data.Password'.

Comment: you can debug using `console.log` to check what kind of value you are getting from `data` and from there trace the source until to the `response.json()`